# Return @JsonAlias value in ControllerAdvice Method Argument Validation (@Valid) response

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation, jackson, spring-validator

I has implemented a simple validation using javax.validation, latest version.

So my class:

```
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Person {

    @NotNull(message = "Required field")
    @JsonAlias(value = "current_name")
    private String name;

    @NotNull(message = "Required field")
    private String age;
}
```

And then I created a Advice to handle and customize the exception message.
Like this:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomRestExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(
            MethodArgumentNotValidException ex,
            HttpHeaders headers,
            HttpStatus status,
            WebRequest request) {

        List<FieldError> errors = ex.getBindingResult().getFieldErrors();

        List<Field> listOfErrors = errors.stream()
                .map(error -> Field.builder()
                        .field(error.getField())
                        .message(error.getDefaultMessage())
                        .build())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        ApiError apiError = new ApiError("validation_error", "Some invalid fields", listOfErrors);
        return handleExceptionInternal(ex, apiError, headers, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, request);
    }
}
```

So, when a get the **error.getField()**, It is a original attribute name: "name". But I need to get the alias: "current_name".

I'm using Jackson lib.

It's possible?

Comment: If you need to read the @JsonAlias in your `handleMethodArgumentNotValid` then you have to inspect the Class using reflection. You can inspect the Person class, get all of its fields and corresponding annotaions, find the JsonAlias for the given field and read the value of the JsonAlias.

Answer (score 1):

In your handleMethodArgumentNotValid method, do the following

1. Find all the fields for current parameter type

```
    Field[] clsFields = ex.getParameter().getParameter().getType().getDeclaredFields();
```

2. Find matching Field and @JsonAlias annotations on that field
3. Read value of the annotation --> which is the value that you put in

```
 @JsonAlias(value = "current_name")
 String name;
```

4. Use that value instead of the original field `error.getField()`

Complete working example:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAlias;
import lombok.*;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.http.*;
import org.springframework.validation.FieldError;
import org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

@SpringBootApplication
public class JsonInspect {
    public static void main(String[] args) { SpringApplication.run(JsonInspect.class, args); }
}
@RestController
class Controller {
    @PostMapping("/test")
    public void t(@RequestBody @Valid Person p) {
        System.out.println(p);
    }
}
@ControllerAdvice
class CustomRestExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {

        Field[] clsFields = ex.getParameter().getParameter().getType().getDeclaredFields();

        List<FieldError> errors = ex.getBindingResult().getFieldErrors();

        List<ErrField> listOfErrors = errors.stream()
                .map(e -> new ErrField(getJsonAlias(clsFields, e), e.getDefaultMessage()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        ApiError apiError = new ApiError("validation_error", "Some invalid fields", listOfErrors);
        return handleExceptionInternal(ex, apiError, headers, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, request);
    }

    String getJsonAlias(Field[] clsFields, FieldError e) {

        JsonAlias[] alisas = getAnnotationsForField(clsFields, e.getField());
        if (alisas == null || alisas.length == 0) {
            return e.getField();
        }

        String[] values = alisas[0].value();
        if (values.length == 0) {
            return e.getField();
        }

        return values[0];
    }
    JsonAlias[] getAnnotationsForField(Field[] clsFields, String fieldName) {
        Optional<Field> first = Stream.of(clsFields).filter(f -> f.getName().equals(fieldName)).findFirst();
        return first.map(field -> field.getAnnotationsByType(JsonAlias.class)).orElse(null);
    }

}

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
class ErrField {
    String fld;
    String message;
}
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
class ApiError {
    String type;
    String message;
    List<ErrField> fields;
}
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Data
class Person {
    @JsonAlias("person_name")
    @NotNull
    String name;
    @NotNull
    String address;
}
```

Required libraries

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Do you know any soultion if we have `List<AnotherDto>` field in our dto and `@JsonAlias` or `@JsonProperty` annotation above? And in this `AnotherDto` in the list can have another List of objects that have `@JsonAliase`s too.